# Selenium Pagefactory-I get Null pointer. WebElement is initialized. Implemented page object pattern

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I'm very new to OOP and Java. I came across this excellent video of page object factory on page object pattern:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u8XH46u1QAw. I tried to implement a similar code for a basic yahoo site and I get a Null pointer error. Can you please help me in troubleshooting this? I appreciate your time. My code is using testNG

Error from console:

```
FAILED: execute
java.lang.NullPointerException
at PageObject.SearchPage.updateSearch(SearchPage.java:16)
```

Code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import PageObject.SearchPage;
public class PgMain {
    WebDriver Browser;
    @BeforeTest
    public void start(){
        Browser=new InternetExplorerDriver ();
    }
    @Test
    public void execute(){
        SearchPage s=new SearchPage(Browser);
        s.navigateTo();
        s.updateSearch();//This is when I get the NPE
    }
    @AfterTest
    public void stop(){
    }       
}


package PageObject;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
public abstract class Abs {
    WebDriver Browser;
    public  Abs(WebDriver Browser){
        this.Browser=Browser;   
    }
    public SearchPage navigateTo(){
        Browser.get("http://finance.yahoo.com/");
        return PageFactory.initElements(Browser, SearchPage.class);     
    }       
}  


package PageObject;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
public class SearchPage extends Abs {
    @FindBy (id="UHSearchProperty")
    private WebElement searchFinancebtn;
    @FindBy (id="UHSearchBox")
    private WebElement usersearchBox;
    public SearchPage(WebDriver Browser){
        super(Browser); 
    }
    public SearchPage  updateSearch(){
        usersearchBox.sendKeys("GOOG");//NPE
        searchFinancebtn.click();
        return PageFactory.initElements(Browser, SearchPage.class); 
    }   
}
```

Comment: You should navigate to the `url` first and then instantiate the search page object

Answer (score 0):

you `initElements` only on the returned instance of SearchPage during `navigateTo()` call.

so for your code to work you'd have to do the following:

```
SearchPage s = new SearchPage(Browser);
s.navigateTo().updateSearch();
```

but to be honest this looks very ugly. Why not just to do the following:

```
WebDriver driver;
SearchPage searchPage;

@Before
public void start() {
    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    searchPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, SearchPage.class);
}
@Test
public void execute() {
    s.navigateTo();
    s.updateSearch();
}
```

Also I'd question the excellence of that video.